# SQL Server Group By after Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to understand how pivot works. I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Marks (
    id int Primary key,
    studentId int,
    course varchar(255),
    marks int
);
```

The data I have is:

```
insert into Marks (id, studentId, course, marks)
Values
(1,1,'Phy',10),
(2,1,'Chem',20),
(3,1,'Math',10),
(4,2,'Phy',20),
(5,2,'Chem',30),
(6,2,'Math',40),
(7,3,'Phy',10),
(8,3,'Chem',40),
(9,3,'Math',10)
```

I am trying to pivot the marks using the course names. I am using the following query:

```
select *
from Marks as m
pivot (max(m.marks) for m.course in ([Phy], [Chem],[Math])) as pivotTable
```

The output I am getting is:

| id | studentId | Phy | Chem | Math |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | (null) | (null) |
| 2 | 1 | (null) | 20 | (null) |
| 3 | 1 | (null) | (null) | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 | (null) | (null) |
| 5 | 2 | (null) | 30 | (null) |
| 6 | 2 | (null) | (null) | 40 |
| 7 | 3 | 10 | (null) | (null) |
| 8 | 3 | (null) | 40 | (null) |
| 9 | 3 | (null) | (null) | 10 |

Ideally, I want something like this:

| id | studentId | Phy | Chem | Math |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 3 | 3 | 10 | 40 | 10 |

I want to understand how pivot is working and how can I group marks by studentId and remove (null).

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing a group by after pivot as your title suggests?

Comment: You can't get it with pivot because Id and studentid cannot be aggregated at the same time. Your query makes more sense without Id being outputted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `SELECT *` especially when you need to `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    studentId
    , MIN(id) AS id
    , MAX(Phy) AS Phy
    , MAX(Chem) AS Chem
    , MAX(Math) AS MAX
FROM Marks AS m
PIVOT (MAX(m.marks) FOR m.course IN ([Phy], [Chem],[Math])) AS pivotTable
GROUP BY studentId
```

| id | studentId | Phy | Chem | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| 7 | 3 | 10 | 40 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0DAEuGfK)

Comment: Not sure what the point of pivoting then grouping again is, might as well just do a single `GROUP BY`

Comment: we don't know, how the database actually looks how many columns he has, maybe this is only for practise purpose

Comment: Either way, still better to just do a normal `GROUP BY`

Comment: i doubt, that it will be that much faster

Comment: Well there is an extra `Stream Aggregate` in the plan https://dbfiddle.uk/vJ_YnFvd but probably depends on indexes. Mainly I was arguing that `GROUP BY` is more flexible than `PIVOT`, which is only useful with long lists.

Answer (score 2):

`PIVOT` basically just does `GROUP BY all_columns_which_are_not_pivoted` so in this case you are getting `GROUP BY id, studentId`.

You might find this easier using a manual conditional aggregation (which is essentially what `PIVOT` does), which is more flexible.

```sql
SELECT
  m.studentId,
  MIN(m.id) AS id,  -- alternatively use ROW_NUMBER()
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.course = 'Phy'  THEN m.marks END) AS Phy,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.course = 'Chem' THEN m.marks END) AS Chem,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.course = 'Math' THEN m.marks END) AS Math
FROM Marks AS m
GROUP BY
  m.studentId;
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer,  PIVOT gets real limited real fast.

Comment: No the question was about pivot

Comment: @nbk The question was how to get the correct result.

Comment: no @Charlieface **I want to understand how pivot is working and how can I group marks by studentId and remove (null).**